# split files on windows compatible with linux cat

Tags: windows

I need to split up a large file on windows so I can upload it in parts to a linux machine. I'm looking to do [the opposite to this](http://elliottback.com/wp/combine-split-files-in-windows/) hopefully with some native utilities to keep it simple.

I understand the linux side of the equation to be `cat filea fileb > file`

what is the simples way to split files on a windows machine which can then be joined together via `cat` on a linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use split from [CoreUtils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) and cat them from Linux

or

- install [7z](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (free) works for Windows and Linux. Use the -v option (volume) -v100m will split the archive into 100MB files.

7z -v option supports b k m g (bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes)

upoad files and extract them from Linux

Comment: or cygwin which will give you the split command on windows (as i've learnt) http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net.html